# xsd: define two possible attributes syntax for an element?

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation, complextype

I need to accept 2 attribute syntax for an element:

```
<fsinfo  line="70" comment="# a comment" />
<fsinfo  line="80" real_dev="/dev/sda2" mount_dev="LABEL=root" mp="/"  fs="ext4" options="defaults" dump="1" pass="1" />
```

I have created an xsd that is able to validate the line 80:

```
<xsd:element name="fsinfo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="line"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="real_dev" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="mount_dev"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="mp" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="fs" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="mkfs_opts"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="options" default="defaults"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="dump" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="pass" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="format"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="comment"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

To validate line 70, I could do:

```
<xsd:element name="fsinfo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="line"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="comment"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

1/ How do I merge both syntaxes so I can validate line 70 and 80?

2/ How can I avoid empty fsinfo tag?

3/ "fsinfo" Attributes can be in any order

Important, if more than "line" and "comment" attribute is present (for example "mount_dev", then all associated required arguments must be present.(line 80 validation scheme)

Note: I can't change my xml file as I must keep compatibility with old software (I'm adding validation to make it more robuste).

Note2: tool used to validate: xmlstarlet --err --xsd myxsdfile.xsd myxmlfile.xml

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I have no information if you can use xsd 1.1 
There is huge possibilities to use asserts which can help you to manage that.

I cannot observe your full xml sample as well as xsd but I could create a sample xsd how to use asserts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="root" type="root"/>
    <xs:complexType name="root">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="fsinfo">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="line"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="real_dev"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="mount_dev"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="mp"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="fs"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="mkfs_opts"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="options"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="dump"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="pass"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="format"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="comment"/>
                    <xs:assert test="(@line and @comment and not(@real_dev) and not(@mount_dev) and not(@mp) and not(@fs) and not(@mkfs_opts) and not(@dump) and not(@pass) and not(@options) and not(@format)) or ((@line and @real_dev and @mp and @fs and @dump and @pass) and ( @mount_dev or @mkfs_opts or @options or @format or @comment))"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll give a try. I'm using xmlstarlet-1.6.1. It is using libxslt-1.1.28.

Comment: The full source of xsd is https://github.com/finley/SystemImager/blob/initrd-from-imageserver-and-dont-package-initrd/lib/dracut/modules.d/51systemimager/disks-layout.xsd

Comment: Examples of files to validate: https://github.com/finley/SystemImager/tree/initrd-from-imageserver-and-dont-package-initrd/doc/examples

Comment: thanks for sharing your xsd, so you can adapt my code example by changing your <xsd:complexType name="fstab_line">.

Comment: I like your solution, bu as I'm using xmlstarlet as parser that uses libxslt, I'm not sure that XML 1.1 is supported. (especially on redhat-6 that I need to support)